# Achieving consistency between Android and iOS apps when using FCM for push notifications

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM has two type of messages

- Notification messages
- Data messages

Behaviour for this type of messages is different for iOS and Android.

Data messages could be received in the background in Android when app even killed, but couldn't by iOS.

Notification messages shows as heads-up in iOS, but goes to tray silently in Android even if priority is high.

We can create custom heads-up notification in Android from data message, but cannot do it in iOS (when app get killed).

My question is how to achieve consistency between this two different platforms?

How to show heads-up notifications for both Android and iOS using Notification messages only or if it possible how to receive data messages in iOS when app is killed and show custom notification?

Implementing two different approaches is ugly by design. What is universal solution that works for both platforms without struggles?